# Adding arrays inside an array from input PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

**My goal**: I wanted to make a list system that stores an array that has 3 values...

```
"Product's Name", 
"Product's Price", 
"Amount of Products".
```

And I want the user to keep adding products and be able sum it all up by multiplying the price by products and summing it all together if there's two or more products in the array.

Expectations:

```
"Milk", 
2.99, 
40

"Apples", 
3.00, 
5
```

My problem is the array input is replacing index 0.

Result:

```
Milk
2.99
40
```

I tried adding the other value, it replaces index 0.
I need some help to understand this problem.

```
<html>
<body>
    <input id="inventory" name="p-name" type="text" placeholder="product name">
    <input id="inventory" name="p-price" type="text" placeholder="product name">
    <input id="inventory" name="p-amount" type="text" placeholder="product name">
    
    <input id="inventory" name="s-name" type="text" placeholder="product name">
    <input id="inventory" name="s-price" type="text" placeholder="product name">
    <input id="inventory" name="s-amount" type="text" placeholder="product name">
    
    <input type=submit name=submit[AddToList] value='Add to list'>
    <input type=submit name=submit[ClearAllList] value='Clear All List'>

<?php
    $listOfInventories = array();

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) { // Checks if user clicked btn.
        $sub = $_POST["submit"];
    
        $time = $_POST["time"];
        $pName = $_POST["p-name"];
        $pPrice = $_POST["p-price"];
        $AmountOfProducts = $_POST["p-amount"];

        $sName = $_POST["s-name"];
        $sPrice = $_POST["s-price"];
        $TimesWorkersLabored = $_POST["s-amount"];
    
        if (isset($sub["AddToList"])) {
            echo " Added to list <br>";
            array_push($listOfInventories, array($pName, $pPrice, $AmountOfProducts)) ;

            foreach ($listOfInventories as $value) {  
                foreach ($value as $x) {
                   echo $x;
                }
            }

            echo count($listOfInventories);

            // Save something;
        } elseif (isset($sub["ClearAllList"])) {
            $listOfInventories = [];
            // Delete something
        }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Adding first product
[image: Adding first product]
Adding second product
[image: Adding second product]

Edit1: Possibly the fault is the initialization array, but where should I put it? It might not work before the array_push.

Comment: Do those `<input>` element exists inside a `<form>` element

Comment: Yes, the input is in a form that uses $_POST global variable.

Comment: Is the HTML and the PHP code in seperate files? If not where is the `<?php` tag

Comment: Oh I forgot the <?php tag

Comment: `submit[ClearAllList]` and `submit[ClearAllList]` and not going to be `if (isset($_POST["submit"]))`

Comment: Please make sure the question makes sense and we dont have to point out 20 errors / bits you missed out before getting the the actual issue

Comment: An `id` in a html document should be unique you have `id="inventory"` on almost all your inputs??

Comment: Can I post pictures to show what I'm talking about?

Comment: Yes Feel free, add to the question

Comment: Also The PHP code is missing a `}` Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239185/discussion-between-mj-delos-santos-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I tried:
<?php echo error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>
and it's saying 22527, what does that mean?

Comment: I think you need to use SESSION to do what you want (this is a normal way to handle things like "shopping cart") -- hence, try something like `$_SESSION["listOfInventories"] = array();` and then `array_push($_SESSION["listOfInventories"], array("Apple", 10.5, 1)) ;`Otherwise, the original item in your cart will disappear when you "add" another item. --- also, make sure you have session_start(); at the top of the script.

Comment: @KenLee it still the same results, 2nd product replaces Index 0. There's no errors though, it just replaces index 0

Comment: Let me give you the sample code (see my answer)

Comment: Oh wait maybe I may be at fault, the initialization might be the one resetting the array. But where should I put it?

Comment: @KenLee where do you think should I put the array initialization variable?

Comment: You see my code: `if (!isset($_SESSION["listOfInventories"]))
{$_SESSION["listOfInventories"] = array();}` initialize the array IF it does not exist , but if it exists, it will not do again , see the point ?

Comment: @KenLee Oh I see the point. It actually worked, it started counting arrays. Is $_SESSION really necessary? or could there be ways where just a variable without Session will work?

Comment: $_SESSION is a very important thing to use in PHP. (It is not difficult to use). For your case (to preserve previous submitted data), it is necessary.  Have a good weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use SESSION to do what you want (this is a rather standard way to handle things like "shopping cart")

Hence, try something like $_SESSION["listOfInventories"] = array(); and then array_push($_SESSION["listOfInventories"], array("Apple", 10.5, 1)) ;

Please try to run the following PHP script, and RELOAD to see the effect - it will preserve the data and add more item(s)

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["listOfInventories"]))
{$_SESSION["listOfInventories"] = array();}

array_push($_SESSION["listOfInventories"], array("Apple", 10.5, 1)) ;

echo count($_SESSION["listOfInventories"]);
echo "....<br>";

array_push($_SESSION["listOfInventories"], array("Orange", 10.5, 1)) ;

echo count($_SESSION["listOfInventories"]);
echo "....<br>";

?>
```

Comment: It says: 
Warning
: session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent in
C:\xampp\htdocs\Test-1\index.php
on line
183

Comment: Please put the session_start() at the TOP of your script

Answer (score 0):

Use method="POST", put your Type="submit" attribute to Submit in Double Quote and Value="".. also put your } at the end of the if statement, add session_start() into the Login file and call only the number of inputs in the Field. use Localhost to store your Timestamp.